# Android relayout issue

Tags: android, layout

help me please

My xml-layout is something like this

```
<LinearLayout width=fill height=wrap orient=horizontal>
  <LinearLayout width=0 height=wrap weight=1>...</>
  <LinearLayout width=0 height=wrap weight=1>...</>
  <LinearLayout width=0 height=wrap weight=1>...</>
  <LinearLayout width=wrap height=wrap weight=0>...</>
</LinearLayout>
```

This inflated `main.xml` does exactly what i need - four groups distributed evenly on screen.

BUT when i start the activity with [for example] second sub-layout visibility `GONE` and make it `VISIBLE` in runtime, whole root/parent layout looks very bad. Subviews  [from sublayouts] messed with each other, looks like their positions didn't recalculate to take into account new `linearlayout` became visible.

`requestLayout()` and `forceLayout()` didn't help.

How can i make the root Layout do the same thing it did when the activity just started?

Comment: when there is a problem with your code or layout, then "pseudocode" isn't a best idea. Post here exact layout that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">........</LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">........</LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">........</LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">........</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set android:weightSum is really interesting, i'll use it. Thanks))

Answer (score 0):

After all i get it works. Now all updates correctly, although i suppose this is not real solution. I just moved code which recalculates layouts visibility to `onWindowFocusChanged` callback and set `android:weightSum` in code manually.
Believe `onSizeChanged` callback also could help.